# How to get values from TableView's static cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have TableView with static cells designed in storyboard.

I want to get the values of the cells in the code.

```
NSMutableArray* questions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
    SurveyCell* qCell = (SurveyCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:i]];
    SurveyCell* aCell = (SurveyCell*)[[self tableView] cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:i]];
    NSString* question = qCell.label.text;
    NSString* answer = aCell.label.text;
    NSDictionary* questionObj = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:question,@"question", answer,@"answer", nil];
    [questions addObject:questionObj];
}
```

Here, somtimes qCell and aCell becomes null. What is the good way to get values from static cells?

Comment: Have you tried .. viewWithTag:<(NSInteger)> ??

Comment: you haven't got a datasource?

Comment: No. Because it is static, I didn't need. Is it the problem?